# Where MongoDB ensureIndex() must be called in JAX-RS/MongoDB/Jackson application?

Tags: mongodb, jax-rs, jackson

I'm following this [example](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/modern-web-apps-using-jax-rs) for creating a simple Web application using JAX-RS, MongoDB and Jackson mapper. Where should I call MongoDB's ensureIndex() if I'd like to have some fields indexed?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ensureIndex()` any time to start indexing fields. It's a blocking call so you will not be able to use the collection while the index is being built.

If you are looking for the function prototype to call from jackson, this might help:

http://vznet.github.com/mongo-jackson-mapper/apidocs/net/vz/mongodb/jackson/JacksonDBCollection.html#ensureIndex(com.mongodb.DBObject)

You can also use the command `db.example.ensureIndex( {<field>: 1 } )` at the `mongo` shell to start the indexing procedure.